# In Laravel 6, how do I query a model based on the properties of its parent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Each Project has many Tasks, this is defined in the Project and Task Models.

When opening a Task by browsing to /tasks/{id}, I want to check if it belongs to a Project that is at a specific Stage before I allow the user to open the Task. Looking for something like this, is there a way to do this?

```
$tasks = Task::where(project->'stage', $current_stage)->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: You can check the stage of the project by saying $task->project->stage. Also, if you want to do something before a request is handle, check out middlewares: https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your variable `$task` and use `first()` because when matching ID, there should only be one answer.

```
$task = Task::with('project')->firstOrFail($id);

if($task->project->stage != $current_stage) {
   // throw your error here, return redirect or whatever
}
```

Comment: I'd note there's no benefit to the `with` when you're just fetching a single row, so this could be simplified to `$task = Task::firstOrFail($id);`. Additionally, OP's probably better off using route model binding so they don't have to do the `Task::firstOrFail` at all - it'd be automatically provided to the function.

Comment: Thanks.
@ceejayoz, don't you need the "with" to allow you to use the "$task->project"?

Comment: @matt9292 No. `with` is for [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) when you're fetching multiple tasks at once.

Comment: I suppose its habit, I always make sure I have the models I need loaded rather than having database queries satisfied in the background, and not necessarily considered.  The project->stage is only detectable by loading project so using `with` or `load` is hardly wasted effort.